# Trying to printf a variable int in C++ causes it to crash. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, printf

Trying to printf a variable int in C++ causes it to crash. Why? Im trying to do the same as in the examples of the printf article in cplusplus.com

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int n;
scanf("%i", &n);
printf("%n is a multiple of 11.", n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Taking a few seconds to grab documentation on `%n`: *returns the number of characters written so far by this call to the function.
The result is written to the value pointed to by the argument.* In any case, your [compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bf3a72650a70c93) could have told you something's up.

Comment: C++ has iostreams to prevent these kinds of mistakes: `if (std::cin >> n) std::cout << n << " is a multiple of 11.\n";` (you'll need to `#include <iostream>` atop your file).  Lots of online explanation, e.g. [random google result](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print out the value of `n`, you probably meant to use [`%d` or `%i`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

```
printf("%d is a multiple of 11.", n);
```